# Can we define irreducible group representations on curved manifolds?

Tags: representation-theory, manifolds

When we have a group G, representation theory is essentially ( tell me if I am wrong ) the characterization of the possible actions of the group G on vector spaces.

In this setting, a main notion is the one of "irreducible" representations, which decomposes the vector space into subspaces invariant by the action of the group, whose (direct-) sum is the original vector space. Here we have all the theory of characters,...

A group can also act on a generic manyfold. I was curious if there is also a notion of irreducibility on a generic manyfold and an analogue of the theory of characters.

My notions are at an introductory level, so excuse me if I said something too wrong but I hope the question makes sense and hope is not too generic.

Comment: One *can* define various notions of irreducibility, but the results won't be particularly useful. Part of the motivation of representation theory is that finite dimensional vector spaces always decompose into lower-dimensional pieces in a way which is very easy to describe. Any corresponding notion of decomposition for manifolds would be extremely complicated, and/or most manifolds would be indecomposable.

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment !